# How to check if a link request is valid before it sends it? (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a simple test project where if you type into an entry any stock ticker symbol it produces a WebClient and link that returns a string of that stock price.

I know the exact URL that I need to acquire the data from, and if the user inputs an existing ticker symbol it works perfectly fine. However, I have a run-time error if the user makes up a ticker symbol, as the program tries to pull data from a non-existent web page.

On run of the application, it goes directly into break mode and returning the error `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`.

How can I check if the URL is valid before making the request or at least be able to catch the error before putting the application into break mode?

This is the c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Stock_WatchList
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class sybmolSelector : ContentPage
    {
        public string price { get; set; }
        public sybmolSelector()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = this;
        }

        private void Entry_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var nameValue = entry.Text.ToString();
            var link = "https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/" + nameValue + "/price?token=Tsk_57bebc1d051340dbaad8656ab0027e90";

            var client1 = new WebClient();
            string b = client1.DownloadString(link);

            price = "$" + b;

            Symbol.Text = nameValue.ToString();
            Price.Text = price;
        }
    }
}
```

and the Xamarin code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Stock_WatchList.sybmolSelector"
             BackgroundColor="Black"
             NavigationPage.IconColor="HotPink">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label TextColor="HotPink" BackgroundColor="Black" Text="------------------- Enter A Symbol Below -------------------" FontSize="19" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
            <Entry PlaceholderColor="HotPink" PropertyChanged="Entry_PropertyChanged" FontSize="19" x:Name="entry" TextColor="HotPink" BackgroundColor="#111111"></Entry>
            <Label x:Name="Symbol" Margin="5" Text="" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="HotPink" FontSize="40"/>
            <Label x:Name="Price" Margin="5,0,5,5" Text="" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="HotPink" FontSize="50"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Where does it throw that exception? Are you sure  `entry` and/or `entry.Text` is initialized before you call tostring on it?

Comment: Is that token yours and do you pay for that? If yes, you better ask a new one, I just used it. Google will find that token as well.

Comment: @rene Entry is the name of the entry in the xamarin code and entry.Text is just calling the value of the entry and then converting the object (entry.Text) into a string that is held under the variable name value.

Comment: @rene it is a working token but it is the sandbox token so it does not charge me.

Comment: Okay, I'm pretty sure Text is null.

Comment: @rene how do you figure

Comment: @rene name.Text is a valid refrence with xamarin

Comment: I have to take a guess as you don't provide on which line that exception occurs. You have that info, it would be helpful if you edited that into the question.

Comment: `entry.Text` is a `string` already, there is no need to call `ToString` on it.  And if the user has not entered any value, it **is possible** for `entry.Text` to be null.  You should test for null before using an object, and you should use exception handling to catch exceptions so they don't crash your app.  Both of these are basic programming strategies you should learn.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a call if Entry.Text is null or empty. When your form gets loaded PropertyChanged will get called. At that moment Text is still null. It certainly doesn't have a default in your markdown.

```
private void Entry_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // guard for null
    if (entry == null) return;
    // no need to call the api if we don't have a value
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Text)) return;

    var link = "https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/" + entry.Text + "/price?token=sometoken";

    using(var client1 = new WebClient()) // WebClient does implement (useless) IDisposable
    {
         price = "$" + client1.DownloadString(link);
    }

    // maybe these are null as well, who knows
    if (Symbol != null)  Symbol.Text = entry.Text;
    if (Price != null)   Price.Text = price;
}
```